# Is it possible to extend SPFieldUrl to have more properties like url or description, to create a custom field type?

Tags: sharepoint-server, development, custom-field-types, spfield

Url field type has more than one property : something like url, description. I want to know that how can I extend url field type(or some other field type that have more than one property) to create a custom field type with more than one property?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the following article:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms441150(v=office.14)